# Is it allowed to use <label> tag without labeled control?

Tags: forms, html, label

I need to show in a page a list of, let's say, person's properties that should be rendered more or less as follow:

> **name:**  Name
>   **date:**  1/1/2000
>   **other:** Other

Reading the [doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) they say:

> *The LABEL element **may** be used to attach information to controls.*

So, is it  the right tag to encompass the names of the properties like *name*, *date*...
even if there's not an `<input>` to associate with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, as per [Quentin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195140/20578).

However, in HTML5, [`<dl>` can be used for generic associations](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) where `<label>` isn’t appropriate.

Comment: Thank you and others.
<dl> with <dt> and <dd>, fits my needs.

Answer (score 6):

No.

It says that it can associate information with controls.

It does not say that it can associate information with anything else.

See also the [newer (but draft) specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label):

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as
>   labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a
>   label element.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen
>   meter output progress select textarea

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct to use the `label` element like that.

The important thing here is the meaning of *may*.

> The LABEL element ***may*** be used to attach information to controls.

[RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) ([which the HTML4 spec follows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/conform.html)) defines *may*:

> **May:** This word, or the adjective "OPTIONAL", mean that an item is truly optional

So here, *may* does not mean the `label` element can be used for other purposes; it just means that it is not required to use a `label` element with controls.

---

As far as alternatives go, it depends what you want to achieve. If you are just trying to follow the spec closely, then I suggest using `p` and a `strong` element for each pair. If you want the data to be more meaningful to computers, you could consider using one of the [Microformat specifications](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page#Specifications).

Answer (score 0):

I partially agree with the answers so far but want to add that if you want to use labels for some reason, then I would display the property values in read-only controls, and then your labels will be valid.

I've done this using appropriate styling to differentiate the read-only controls from the functioning controls to avoid confusing your users. This was on a sequence of pages which built up the information gathered from the user in a wizard.

I have this link to W3C - the "Editor's Draft" as opposed to the link above which is the "Working Draft", which states that you can associate it with any element - as long as it's 'labelable' - even though this is a subsection of the Form section. It states earlier that a labelable element does not have to be within a form.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-label-element